# Able to install OpenAm but not able to login

Tags: ansible, openam

I only wanted openAm to be installed thus able to install the same via the ansible script([Github link](https://github.com/ForgeRock/frstack)). I have used the OpenAm version 14 Snapshot from the maven repository. But i am not able to login with the credential after successful script run.

amAdmin / password

I rechecked and the variable is set as below located at

[amadmin_password: password](https://github.com/ForgeRock/frstack/blob/master/ansible/group_vars/all)

Let me know if i need to do anything more.

The target machine is not showing signs of error. but the login is failing

I looked into the embedded ldap which got created. I have not found the user amAdmin

[image]

The code is directly taken from the github published by forgerock but i have stripped it to run only openam. Please find the task/main.yml file. All the dependent files can be assumed as there in the github.Currently it is able to connect to the external LDAP and create an embedded LDAP. The script was successful during run

```
- file: path="{{ install_root}}" owner="{{ fr_user }}" state="directory"

- file: path={{ install_root}}/openam owner={{fr_user}} state="directory"

- name: Create staging  directory
  file: path=/var/staging state=directory owner={{ fr_user }}  mode=0777

- name: Download openam snapshot
  shell: 'wget http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/releases/org/forgerock/openam/openam-server/12.0.0/openam-server-12.0.0.war -O /var/staging/openam.war creates=/var/stag$
  register: openam_downloaded


- name: Deploy war to tomcat
  command: creates="{{ tomcat_openam_dir }}/webapps/openam" cp "{{ staging_dir }}/openam.war" "{{ tomcat_openam_dir}}/webapps/openam.war"

- name: copy service from openam to init.d to install it as service
  template: src=openam.service dest="/etc/init.d/openam.service"  mode=0777

- name: Updates all the release candidate as defaults
  shell: 'update-rc.d openam.service defaults'
  register: allRC_Updated

  - file: path="{{ install_root}}" owner="{{ fr_user }}" state="directory"


- file: path={{ install_root}}/openam owner={{fr_user}} state="directory"

- name: Ensure openam tomcat instance is running
  service: name="openam.service" state=restarted enabled=yes

- name: Wait for openam war to be fully deployed before running configurator
  wait_for: port="{{openam_server_port}}" delay=10

- wait_for: port={{openam_server_port}} delay=30

- name: Run ssoconfigure
  ssoconfigure: server_url="http://{{openam_fqdn}}:{{openam_server_port}}"
    deployment_uri="/openam"
    base_dir="{{install_root}}/openam"
    directory_server="{{embedded_dj_host}}"
    root_suffix="o=openam"
    directory_admin_port="{{embedded_dj_admin_port}}"
    directory_jmx_port="{{embedded_dj_jmx_port}}"
    directory_port="{{embedded_dj_ldap_port}}"
    ds_dirmgrdn="{{embedded_dj_dirmgr}}"
    data_store="embedded"
    ds_dirmgrpasswd="{{embedded_dj_password}}"
    userstore_ssl="SIMPLE"
    userstore_host="{{opendj_host}}"
    userstore_port="{{opendj_ldap_port}}"
    userstore_suffix="{{opendj_basedn}}"
    userstore_mgrdn="{{opendj_dirmgr}}"
    userstore_passwd="{{opendj_password}}"
    amldapuserpasswd="{{amldapuser_password}}"
    cookie_domain="{{openam_cookie_domain}}"
    admin_pwd="{{amadmin_password}}"
    acceptlicense="true"
    am_enc_key="AQICY6Za5J5noktyqnhW10JiPVNUdKuiZYwS"
    lb_site_name="sitea"
    lb_primary_url="{{openam_site_url}}"

- file: recurse=yes state=directory  owner="{{ fr_user }}"  path="{{ install_root}}" mode=0775
```

I have taken one more role from the forgerock github location called ssoadm (task/main.yml) as follows. I ran both the roles in same machine. I see no change.

```
- file: name="{{ install_root}}/ssoadmin" owner={{ fr_user }} state=directory

- name: Download ssoadmintools snapshot
  shell: 'wget http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/releases/org/forgerock/openam/openam-distribution-ssoadmintools/12.0.0/openam-distribution-ssoadmintools-12.0.0.zip -O /$
  register: ssoadmintools_downloaded

- unarchive: src={{ staging_dir }}/ssoadmintools.zip dest="{{ install_root}}/ssoadmin" copy=no

- file: path="{{ install_root }}/ssoadmin" owner="{{ fr_user}}" mode=0777 recurse=yes

- name: setup ssoadm tools
  command: chdir={{ install_root }}/ssoadmin {{ install_root }}/ssoadmin/setup -p {{ install_root }}/openam --acceptLicense
  environment:
    JAVA_HOME:  /opt/java/oracle/jdk1.7.0_71

- template: src=ssoadm-patch dest="{{install_root}}/ssoadmin/openam/bin/" mode=0755 owner={{fr_user}}
- command: chdir="{{install_root}}/ssoadmin/openam/bin" ./ssoadm-patch

- file: recurse=yes state=directory  owner="{{ fr_user }}" path="{{ install_root}}/ssoadmin" mode=0775
```

Comment: I looked into the file system to check if i can find anything. Following is what i saw in one file..   .....................               .....................   

                                                            ubuntu@ip-172-31-5-29:/opt/ois/openam/openam$ cat openam_mon_auth
demo AQICGnKMFCop14LnksconpWmnvU6sr2RRBFr . Does it mean the 'demo' user can login. What is the password ?

Comment: - name: Run ssoconfigure
  ssoconfigure: server_url="http://ec2-XXX.compute1.amazonaws.com:8080"
......
    admin_pwd="password" #hardcoded here but still did not work.
    acceptlicense="true"
    am_enc_key="AQICY6Za5J5noktyqnhW10JiPVNUdKuiZYwS"
    lb_site_name="sitea"
    lb_primary_url="{{openam_site_url}}"

Comment: have you tried explicitly specify the admin console? https://<your host and port>/openam/XUI/#login/&authIndexType=service&authIndexValue=adminconsoleservice

Comment: I tried again. has thrown an error for me "Unable to login to OpenAM" on the browser screen. I was hitting http://ec2-5-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/openam/XUI/#login/ for logging in . Error as below . 106.216.133.107 - - [19/Jan/2016:08:29:52 +0000] "POST /openam/json/users?_action=idFromSession HTTP/1.1" 401 62
106.216.133.107 - - [19/Jan/2016:08:29:52 +0000] "POST /openam/json/authenticate?authIndexType=service&authIndexValue=adminconsoleservic%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Be HTTP/1.1" 400

Answer (score 0):

What cookie domain are you using for your installation?
In the ansible scripts the cookie domain is specified in a property called "openam_cookie_domain". You can also see which cookie domain is set by going to "openam/json/serverinfo/*"

".amazonaws.com" is classed as a top level domain and therefore can't have cookies set on it. If the OpenAM server cannot set cookies properly authentication will fail.

The best option will be to use a different domain altogether (i.e. ".example.com"), otherwise you can use the amazon instance FQDN ("ec2-XXX.compute1.amazonaws.com") as your cookie domain.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , truely ,i am using the .amazonaws.com cookie domain as that is the easiest i can do and without buying any domain, still facing the issue. I will try to replicate it once more and post my finding...

Comment: If using your own domain is not an option you'll have to use the hostname ("ec2-XXX.compute1.amazonaws.com") as your cookie domain. You can add multiple cookie domains in the future as required once you can access the admin console.

Comment: yes , it needs to be amazonaws.com for aws instances . But that probably not the issue as i used the domain correctly.. I have only used one role "Openam" as in the code above. I see most of the code related to ssoconfigtool is commented so probably may not need that role. but ssoadm role may be required , still exploring what needs to be modified. also the amadmin user is not visible in the embedded ldap so am wondering what i have missed.

Comment: You don't need roles to access the admin console. Also, the "amadmin" user is not stored as a regular LDAP user. Can you take a look at the HTTP response you get from the /json/authenticate endpoint? Do you get a "tokenId" attribute in the JSON response? If so, it means that authentication was successful and that something else is failing. You can also look for errors in the javascript console.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use host-based cookies (remove all cookie domains from platformservice) when running OpenAM in Amazon Cloud as Amazon listed them as public suffix (see https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat) so browsers have to drop the domain cookie issued by OpenAM.

You need to install ssoadm and use

`ssoadm -u amadmin -f PATH_TO_PWDFILE remove-attr-defs -s iPlanetAMPlatformService -t global -a iplanet-am-platform-cookie-domains`

Comment: Looks like this may be issue. The Error shows the user is not created with openam role(viewed the opendj via ldap browser confirming the same).      "2016-01-19 08:53:04"   "Login Success|isNoSession=false"       9277c6f925ee63e401      id=amadmin,ou=user,o=openam     106.216.133.107 INFO    o=openam       AUTHENTICATION-100       "cn=dsameuser,ou=DSAME Users,o=openam"  "Not Available"DataStore        106.216.133.107